When is confirmation or acknowledgement desirable in a mail dialogue?
In a mail dialogue, when is confirmation or acknowledgement desirable? Or to put it differently, when does the conversation end and both parties are clear on what is agreed to?
For example (shortened):

A: Can we meet to discuss issue Y?
B: Yes, let's meet, I am available Friday at 10.
A: Thanks in advance! Can person C join us?
B: Yes, absolutely.

Is confirmation by A required or desirable or would that be overdone?

As my rule of thumb, the longest the discussion, the more the confirmation is required.
I deal a lot with everyday Q/A with students and customers.
To a single question / need, I just acknowledge and end with a:

dully noted/done for "question Q", thanks (well, you get the idea, it can be straight to the point or a little more sugar coated, depending on who you're answering to).

so my interlocutor knows it's a closing tag and that I've taken care of their request. Simple and efficient. Sometimes, I get a laconic "thanks" in return, and sometimes, nothing, it doesn't matter and changes nothing to the exchange/point.
When the discussion has been going back and forth, and multiple points discussed, I usually make sure we both understood each other well. So, my closing sentence will be a summarized version of our written exchanges:

so, we'll meet on Friday 9th, at 10:00 AM, in my office, Alice and Bob will join us to talk about project C. See you there, cheers/best regards (again, you get the point, it depends on the persons involved)

If you misunderstood something, your interlocutor will have your last sentence on top of the email and can correct right away. I almost never encountered a problem over the years, if you apply the "concise and precise reminder" rule of meeting closing.
In your case, I'd summarize in a last reply, with all points put together in a  sentence:

It's ok, meeting scheduled with you and C about issue Y on Friday at 10. Thanks.

